Trying to do multiple joins in a single pyspark dataframe
Without going into too much detail, I am trying to bring together a bunch of rows into a single entry. I have simplified my "source" and "target" dataframes below.
Source DF:



ID
Date
Device
Payload




1
12/24
null
null


null
12/24
DeviceA
a


null
12/24
DeviceB
b



Destination DF:



ID
Date
Payload_DeviceA
Payload_DeviceB




1
12/24
a
b



So as you can probably guess, I am starting with the entry that has a value for "id".  I then need to do a search based on date and then a specific device name.  In the result, I want to alias that column.  Once I get this working, I'd like to make a loop in order to iterate through all of the device types that might be found in the "Device" column (there will be a varying number of devices).
So here is where I am stuck.  I know how to do the first join:
(df1
.join(df1, on=join_condition, how='left')
.show()
)
I also know that I can add multiple joins by chaining "join" statements together. In that single join, I can alias the resulting "Payload" column so that it is printed out as "Payloadx".
The question I have is this:  how can I do this if I want to do multiple joins against the same dataframe?  I am purposely not showing any more code here as I have tried a variety of ways (including using aliases, which gave me errors about the dataframes being ambiguous).
So I am coming here to ask this:  is it even possible?  If so, if someone could point me to the technique that needs to be used to do it, I am sure that I could fill in the rest.

The second join is done for example purposes only.  It could have been accomplished in the first join, of course.
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

def populate_df1():
    df1_temp = spark.createDataFrame([    
    ('101','Donald','California','107'),
    ('102','Catherine','Texas','103'),
    ('103','Miller','Miami','104'),
    ('104','Maxerine','Miami','106'),
    ('105','Daniel','Chicago','106'),
    ('106','Kate','NewYork','107'),
    ('107','Will','California','108')    
    ], ['id','name','location','manager_id'])
    return df1_temp

df2 = populate_df1()
display(df2)


(df2.alias("emp_df")
    .join(df2.alias("mgr_df"), col("emp_df.manager_id") == col("mgr_df.id"), how='left')
    .join(df2.alias("location_df"), col("emp_df.manager_id") == col("location_df.id"), how='left')
    .select(col("emp_df.*"), col("mgr_df.name").alias("mgr_name"), col("location_df.location").alias("mgr_location"))
    .show()
)   

